# Why Array.to_s is not recursive?

Tags: crystal-lang

The `Array.to_s` uses `inspect` on its content, instead of calling `to_s` recursively.

This code

```
class Some
  def to_s; "some" end
end

puts [Some.new].to_s
```

Would produce `[#<Some:0x10078ce80>]`, instead of `[some]`

Wondering if there could be any bad consequences if I override `Array.to_s` to use `to_s` recursively? And why it's not working this way by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you stringify a collection, you need every collection item to be self contained in order to distinguish between one and the other. `#inspect` takes care of that because it's supposed to stringify the value in an unambiguous way.

For example, if `Array#inspect` used `#to_s` on the items, the result of `["a", "b,c", 'd'].to_s` would be `"[a,b,c,d]"` and you can't tell how many items are even in the collection or what types they have.